# Is there any PPA for ralink 3090 64bit?

Tags: wireless, drivers, ppa, ralink

Is there any PPA for ralink 3090 64bit?

I have just added this [markus-tisoft](https://launchpad.net/~markus-tisoft/+archive/ppa) PPA but I have not found any driver for ralink 3090 yet in Synaptic Package Manager. (it is only available for 32bit only).

For now, I have downloaded manually. but I hope this PPA available for 64bit arch so I can get it updated automatically.

Or any PPA for this 64bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching Launchpad, there is no current PPA for 64bit driver of ralink 3090 that I can see.

The markus-tisoft ppa does not have a maverick entry list.  So maybe something in the future, perhaps.

Comment: yeah, I hope markus-tisoft add entry for 64bit arch. whereas the Driver is noarch. so, it can be easily just copy in the amd64 repos and add some extra adjustment in dist folder.